# A few users cannot view a list

Tags: permissions, access

So I have this user group with customized permissions.

- Add only on list A
- Edit only on list B

It worked well all this time for that group with those permissions. But a few days ago I added a few new users to the group, but those users cannot even view list B (it doesn't show in their SharePoint site).

Does anyone know if there's an issue from SharePoint on this matter?

Thank you, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant the view permission on site level to the new users.

Comment: thank you so much this fix the problem. before it was not 'Read' permission on site level for the new users.

Comment: @kalistalanti Pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You have to review the List Permission for the "List B". Make sure the new users can able to access "List B".